# Google Drive error: "Invalid MS-DOS function". Is there a workaround?

Tags: windows, google-docs, google-drive-for-desktop

I'm using the official Google Drive client for Windows, and I'm using Windows Explorer to attempt to copy Google Documents (.gdoc files) from my Google Drive to a local Windows folder, as a way of backing up those files, in case I ever lose access to my account.

Windows repeatedly gives me the error:

> **Invalid MS-DOS function.**

[image]

One known workaround is to login to https://drive.google.com and download the files that way, however this converts them to DOCX format and also cannot be automated.

Is there any other known workaround to backup GDOC files in an efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

*.gdoc* or *.gsheet* are not actual files, they are just shortcuts to open the actual files saved in the cloud (is your whole Google Doc only 174 bytes?)

Therefore there is no point (and this is why they prevent it, so that you don't fool yourself that you actually copied something) copying those links.

What you might be able to do with a Google Apps Script is backup those Docs/Sheets periodically to a Docx/Xlsx file and copy those from your sync to your local backup. See here such an idea of a script https://stackoverflow.com/a/54724969/5518385 or see the script and instructions here (and the links there to other options) https://gist.github.com/brokensandals/6b77f73666323d6e4b94ff1df12a532a

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR

Unfortunately, there is no way to back up Google Docs documents (intentionally using the term *document* instead of *file*), keeping all the features that might a document might have and be used to recover a document exactly as it was at the time that the back up was created.

##### Explanation

1. No offline version can be viewed independently of Google Chrome and Google Docs perpetually.
2. Google Docs has unique features like *smart chips* that are not supported in file formats like Microsoft Word (DOCX), PDF, etc.
3. Google Docs API and Google Apps Script don't support all the available features through the Google Docs apps (Web, Windows and MacOS).

##### How to backup Google Docs documents content

As of May 9, 2023, use Google Takeout to make a general backup of your Google Docs files. When configuring the backup, you can set the file format used. The instructions are in Google Account Help Center : [How to download your Google data](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en).

###### Google Takeout highlights about backing up Google Docs documents

Go to https://takeout.google.com/, read the page carefully and follow the instructions. Regarding creating a backup of your Google Documents,

Go to the Drive  section:

[image]

Click on Multiple Formats

[image: Multiple Formats]

On Documents, select the file format to be used for your Google Docs documents.

##### About Google Docs files downloaded by Google Drive for Desktop

Google Drive for Desktop for Windows creates file shortcuts to Google Docs documents using the extension `.gdoc`, but it doesn't download the content. This works this way because Google Documents content is not handled in the same way that desktop operating systems like Windows, MacOS, Unix, etc., handle a file.

You can use a Notepad or text editor to inspect the .gdoc content. In this Windows file, you will find the URL of the Google Docs document. When Google Drive for Desktop for Windows, it sets Windows to handle .gdocs files as file shortcuts pointing to a webpage. This means double-clicking a .gdocs file will be opened using the default web browser.

Google Documents content is managed by a web application that pulls content from "the cloud". This means the document content might be stored in multiple data centers instead of a single storage unit, as most desktop computer use.

You might export a Google Document as PDF, DOCX among other formats, from Google Drive (https://drive.google.com) or use the Google Drive API, Google Apps Script or a third-party service to convert the one or multiple files to one of the supported file formats, i.e., DOCX, but some features will not be included. For example, these files can't be used to recover the 100% of that you see in a Google Docs document.

Comment: OK, thanks for the great tip. This is a pretty good option considering that you can filter the export to only include specific folders. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an option to retain the original GDOC format, which could possibly mean there is some slight loss of formatting or features. But it might be adequate. Cheers.

Comment: @SimonE  Thanks. In case that you aren't following this answer, I updated it.